# Apache2-Error (36)File name too long

Tags: apache, http

we are using Apache2 as an Frontend for a Software called Kibana, which in his new version generate a very long URL-Get HTTP Request like.

GET https://server.domain.lan/logstash-2014.06.30,logstash-2014.07.01,logstash-2014.07.02,logstash-2014.07.03,logstash-2014.07.04,logstash-2014.07.05,logstash-2014.07.06,logstash-2014.07.07,logstash-2014.07.08,logstash-2014.07.09,logstash-2014.07.10,logstash-2014.07.11,logstash-2014.07.12,logstash-2014.07.13,logstash-2014.07.14,logstash-2014.07.15,logstash-2014.07.16,logstash-2014.07.17,logstash-2014.07.18,logstash-2014.07.19,logstash-2014.07.20,logstash-2014.07.21,logstash-2014.07.22,logstash-2014.07.23,logstash-2014.07.24,logstash-2014.07.25,logstash-2014.07.26,logstash-2014.07.27,logstash-2014.07.28,logstash-2014.07.29,logstash-2014.07.30/_aliases?ignore_missing=true

Well this request run into an error cause apache seems not to be able to handle request that longer than 255 characters.

If tried setting 
LimitRequestLine 1638000000000
        LimitRequestFieldSize 163800000000
        LimitXMLRequestBody 163800000000
        LimitRequestBody 0
        LimitRequestFields 5000000
but unfortunately this didnt work.

Is there any chance to make this work, or do i have to use the nginx-proxy?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

to overcome that we have split elastic search from kibana in apache conf:

```
<Location /elasticsearch>
  ProxyPass http://localhost:9200
  ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:9200
</Location>
```

and pointed ti new location in kibana/config.js

```
elasticsearch: "http://your.host.here/elasticsearch"
```

Works for us.